# What do you do if you feel a question was closed... But for the wrong reason?

Tags: support, flagging

I was looking at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/628932/how-to-install-jd-decomplier-for-eclipse-juno) question last night and flagged it as low quality.

It was later closed by a moderator, but because it was about a *product or service recommendation*.

The question doesn't ask for a recommendation, but for a location of a file to download (JD Decompiler Plugin).

Does it matter that the flag is wrong, as far as I can tell (I haven't started flagging things until recently, I thought you lost 1 rep for each flag), and if it is, should anything be done about it?

If the flag is correct *for this question*, what would I do in the future if I was **sure** that the flag was wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, reputation is not tied to flags in any way. The only way you can lose rep from a flag is if you're on the *receiving* end of a spam flag.

Flags can be *declined*, which affects flag weight. Flag weight doesn't really do much on Super User because we have relatively few flags compared to a site like Stack Overflow. It only matters if you have so many declined flags that your flags are hidden altogether. That almost never happens. Regardless, your flag was accepted.

There is no actual "very low quality" close reason, so the moderator had to choose the most appropriate reason. In this case, I think he was correct in choosing the software recommendation reason. The person is essentially asking where to download the software. That's close enough, in my opinion.

Keep in mind, if you select "this question doesn't belong here or is a duplicate" in the flag box, you can then choose a close reason to flag the question for. This can also put the question into the close vote review queue for users with >3000 reputation to review. That makes the process faster by not requiring intervention from a diamond moderator.

Comment: I would probably even recommend never to flag a question as VLQ unless it's to be deleted right away. That's why we have the close reasons – users without close privileges can now still push questions to the close vote queue.